# what might the problem be? after I post, what I have in the database does not include the provider's Id and I specified t as a field in the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose ORM for mongoDB in a nodejs project and have this schema where I'm trying to make sure a doctor can write medical history for a patient and the patient can also rate doctor along with other fields to get patient's information:

```
    const recipientSchema = new Schema({
      ...
      history: [{
        provider: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Provider',
          required: true
        },
        symptoms: { type: String, required: true },
        diagnosis: { type: String, required: true },
        notes: { type: String, required: true },
        prescriptions: { type: String, required: true },
        createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
      }],
      ratings: [{
        doctor: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Provider',
        },
        score: {type: Number, default: 0}
      }],
    }, { timestamps: true });
```

I also have this controller to post to patient's history to the database:

```
    async function postHistory(req, res){
      try{
        const { providerId, symptoms, diagnosis, notes, prescriptions } = req.body;

        // Update the recipient's history record
        const recipient = await Recipient.findById(req.params.id);
        recipient.history.push({
          provider: providerId,
          symptoms,
          diagnosis,
          notes,
          prescriptions
        });
        await recipient.save();

        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'History submitted successfully.' });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while submitting the history.'});
      }
    });
```

This is my mock:

```
{
    "provider": "6487108816960b932819019e",
    "symptoms": "test",
    "diagnosis": "test",
    "notes": "test",
    "prescriptions": "test"
}
```

This is kind of what's in the database:

```
{  ...  
"history": [{
"symptoms": "test",
"diagnosis": "test",
"notes": "test",
"prescriptions": "test",
...
}
],
...
}
```

The provider field is missing! I've tried deleting and reposting but it's the same result still.

I expect something like this:

```
{  ...  
"history": [{
"provider": ObjectId("64878a7e965a33c829585f68"),
"symptoms": "test",
"diagnosis": "test",
"notes": "test",
"prescriptions": "test",
...
}.


],
...
}
```

if you look in the schema, you'd see I have two refs, the other ref(ratings) has no problem, every field reflects when I post to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your mock doesn't match what `postHistory` expects to be in `req.body`:

```
// expected is `providerId`...
const { providerId, symptoms, diagnosis, notes, prescriptions } = req.body;
        ^^^^^^^^^^

// ...but you're mocking with `provider`
"provider": "6487108816960b932819019e",
 ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Do you know how much of a lifesaver you are??? I mean i was up all night... Thanks so much, it worked.